# Replace category titles

Tags: categories, filters, hooks, wp-head, wp-title

I want to display different titles in category archives than the category title.

I have created a function with if statements for this purpose:

```
function category_titles_change() {
    if (is_category('name1')) { ?>  
        new title 1
    <?php }
    elseif (is_category('name2')) { ?>  
        new title 2
    <?php }
    elseif (is_category('name3')) { ?>  
        new title 3
    <?php }
}
```

How can I use this to change the `<title></title>` shown in the `<head></head>`

I have tried this:

```
function head_category_titles_change() {    
 if (is_category()) { ?> 
 <title> 
<?php category_titles_change(); ?> 
 </title> 
<?php }}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'head_category_titles_change' );
```

But this ads a second `<title>` to the `<head>` in addition to the default title.
How can I replace the default Title in Category archives with my desired titles?

Answer (score 4):

Well thank you for this question i did this after you posted this

```
function category_title( $title ){
if( is_category('name1') ){
    $title = 'name1 title';
}elseif( is_category('name2') ){
    $title = 'name2 title';
}
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'category_title' );
```

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 for the effort, but doesn't work. Doesn't have any effect.

Comment: It woks if I use `add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'category_title' );`

Comment: It worked in my archive page bro

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `wp_head` action - it doesn't give you a chance to modify title that is already printed. But WordPress has special hook for that: [`wp_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/).

The code below should do the trick:

```
function my_change_category_title( $title, $sep ) {
    if ( is_category('name1') ) {
        return 'Cat 1 title';
    }
    if ( is_category('name2') ) {
        return 'Cat 2 title';
    }
    ...

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_change_category_title', 10, 2 );
```

You can also try to use [`pre_get_document_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_document_title/) hook with the same filter function.

Comment: +1 for the effort, but doesn't work. Doesn't have any effect.

Comment: And does your theme use `wp_title` at all? Do you use any SEO plugins that may rewrite the title?

Comment: I don't use any Seo plugins. There is no `wp_title` in my functions. There is only: `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' ); ` and this code changing the separator: `add_filter( 'document_title_separator', 'xxx_title_separator' );
function xxx_title_separator( $sep ) {
    $sep = '';
    return $sep;}` Maybe we should use `'document_title_parts'` or `wp_get_document_title()`?

Comment: It woks if I use `add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'my_change_category_title' );`